# HP Proliant DL360 G7 Wont Boot from USB

Tags: windows, hp, hp-proliant, usb-boot

Whenever I try to boot from a USB stick I get the Red Screen Of Death. I've tried to load VMWare, Windows and Linux from a bootable USB but nothing.

[image: Picture of error]

Comment: Did you just buy this off eBay? Clear the NVRAM first.

Answer (score 2):

Reboot again. (cold Boot) 
Press F9 to enter the RBSU
Check, if the „USB Boot Support“ is enabled. 
If not, enable it.
Go to „System Options“ > „USB Options“ > „Removable Flash Media Boot Sequence“ and select the proper boot device there.
Then select “Standard Boot Order” (IPL) and choose to start from “USB Drive Key (C:)” first.

In Reference to
https://seiler.it/red-screen-death-illegal-opcode-error/

Answer (score 0):

I had to replace the CMOS Battery of my HP ProLiant MicroServer Gen8 - I spent all day yesterday trying all kinds of stuff but then today I remembered someone mentioning the CMOS Battery.

Changed it, plugged the power in and suddenly Windows can install!

Comment: Hi, the question state a HP server, can you elebarate on why it could be the same problem than the OP you fixed, thanks!

Comment: @yagmoth555 thought everyone knew the MicroServer is a ProLiant...